# sluggish video. ubuntu 16.04, core 2duo 2.00Ghz

Tags: 16.04, video, inspiron

trying to recycle a nice old laptop Inspiron 1720. Its got a core2duo 2Ghz Intel centrino processor, 4GB ram. I installed ubuntu 16.04 on it. it performs pretty ok until I trying stream video. youtube isnt so bad but some other streaming websites are really slow and practically unwatchable unless i close all other browser windows. If I have system monitor open which streaming a video it seems to run piggish as well. I presume it puts an extra load on the CPU.

i use firefox ordinarily but i installed konqueror as well to try that but it was much the same. CPU usage was over 50% when watching a video, and the video is self became glitchy and sluggish.

is my system spec up to ubuntu16.04? I'm just using the laptop for basic internet usage, not much else. i could go try lubuntu if you think that would be a better bet. I thought my spec looked ok though judging from the minimum spec requred by ubuntu16

any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: you could try lubuntu, but this looks fine to me. what graphics card is this?

Comment: Which video sites are sluggish specifically? Can you provide one or two example video links? Do you have and use Flash Player to view them? Which GPU does the computer have and which GPU driver does Ubuntu use for it (see the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -A2 VGA`)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok there are a number of considerations with re-purposing older hardware (and congrats on re-purposing rather than throwing out!).

1. Any ability to upgrade RAM and HDD will provide a benefit. A lot of laptops have ready access to RAM and HDD compartments (just under a couple of screws on the underside of the laptop). Search on youtube/google for "Dell Inspiron RAM & Hard Disk Replacement / Upgrade" or similar. RAM is very cheap, just make sure you check on say Dell website or google for the Inspiron 1720 manual so you can see what RAM is compatible. SSD's offer a huge improvement over old spinning hard drive and are reasonably priced these days.
2. Desktop environment. Google for "linux desktop gnome, lxde, unity, kde ram usage", there are lists of how much RAM each kind of desktop environment uses. Lubuntu and Xubuntu are generally decent choices given your graphics card appears to have very limited RAM of 384Mb.
3. Unnecessary apps. Remove anything you don't need. Deja Dup backup is one I usually remove straight away as I personally find it slows my system down... a lot. Remove other things you don't need like printer deamons if you don't print, snap if you don't need containerized apps, etc
4. Lightweight app alternatives. Firefox and Chrome can be a bit heavy on memory usage. Lightweight browsers include IceWeasal and Midori. Again google for options. When streaming videos don't stream in 1080p, you'll have to be satisfied with lower resolutions (perhaps 480p or less).
5. Let another machine do all the heavy lifting. If you have another higher spec'd pc available you may be able to leverage that machine to do all the 'heavy lifting' for you. Use something like X2Go, Xpra, FreeNX, VirtualGL, etc to run applications on the better machine, with the output directed back to your laptop. This kind of scenario is generally referred to as a thin client solution.
6. Proprietary vs open source graphics drivers. I think given the age of your laptop this won't make much difference but perhaps if you've tried everything else without decent results then installing a proprietary graphics driver could assist.

Last resort is to actually choose a lighter distro. I've personally found Porteus OS to be very responsive on old hardware (I had it running in 384Mb of system RAM on a very very old laptop). Google for "linux lightweight distros"